# django template anchor tag not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a header in my webpage and a logo in that header. I want to insert an anchor tag in that logo which points to my home page which is index.html page,despite which ever view or page is called. I have created a base.html,a snippet of which is:

```
<div class="header">
            <div class="inner_header">
                <div class="logo">

                    <a href='#'><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="logo" /> </a>

                </div>
```

I have extended this base.html to all my other template files

My url pattern that points to my index page and to other pages is this:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
        url(r'^latest/(?P<latest_title_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.latest, name='latest'),
        url(r'^headline/(?P<heading_title_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.headline, name='headline'),)
```

I have tried using `<a href="index.html">,<a href=''>` and bunch of other things which doesn't produce the desired result or gives an error. What is the appropriate way to do this without writing lot of codes ?

Comment: Did you try: `<a href="{% url 'index' %}">`?

Comment: `href=#` does not point to a different page, eg in index, it is jus an empty bookmark.

Comment: thanks @RohitJain it helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rohit Jain's suggestion of using the `url` template tag is correct

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">
```

But it might help to understand what your current approaches are doing

- `<a href='#'>` - This is trying to link to an id element on your page, but since you haven't provided an id name it just refers to the page itself. It doesn't redirect anywhere
- `<a href="index.html">` - You are trying to refer to the template directly, to which you don't have a urlpattern that maps this url to a view that would then display that template
- `<a href=''>` - This is pretty much the same as using `#` since you're not changing the the link you're appending to

You may have some success with `<a href="/">` but again, this isn't the correct way to do it in django since you may decide in the future to change what url pattern matches up to a particular view (i.e you decide to add i18n patterns) so you should *always* try to use the `url` template tag.